# SQL join query where foreign key has non of these fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables created as follows:

```
create table table1(
    id number(10) not null,
    constraint table1_pk primary key (id)
);

create table table2(
    table1_id number(10) not null,
    x number(10) not null,
    constraint table1_fk foreign key (table1_id) references table1(id)
);
```

Next I inserted some random data into both of those tables. table1 includes all IDs from 1 - 1000, table2 includes ids from table1 in the table1_id field, and a random number between 0 and 2 in the x field. Every table1_id can have multiple lines, but can only have each x value one time. Therefore table2 looks like this:

```
TABLE1_ID   X
    1       0
    1       1
    2       0
    2       2
    3       0
    4       2
    5       0
    6       2
    7       2
    8       0
    8       1
```

I want to select all rows from table1 where the matching table1_id in table2, has neither 1s or 2s in the x column (for above example the result should contain only id 3 and id 5). However, if I add number 3 to to possible choices for x, the correct results would include all fields, which have 0 or 3, and do not have 1 or 2.

The following query does what I want, but unfortunately it is too slow:

```
select * from table1 where id not in (select t1.id from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id where t2.x = 1 or t2.x = 2);
```

I'm not an SQL expert by any means, but I'm pretty sure there is a faster way to do this, maybe via a different join or by adding indices (I tried that but it didn't help). Maybe someone more of an expert can help me find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Since I've tried some queries now, and all of them took about the same time (0.8s) I have another question: table1 has 1000 rows, table2 has 1569 rows. Is 0.8s actually reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

I would write this using `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.table1_id = t1.id and
                        t2.x in (1, 2)
                 );
```

Then for performance, you want an index on `table2(table1_id, x)`.

Comment: You forget the t2 after table2. Otherwise the query does what it should, although slower than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with performance is mostly due to the table structure. If I were to do this, I would merge the two tables like this:

```
create table table1(
    id number(10) not null,
    hasValue0 bit,
    hasValue1 bit,
    hasValue2 bit,
    constraint table1_pk primary key (id)
);
```

So now, whenever you are inserting a new entry of (3, 1) to your table2, instead you should run an update query like this:

```
update table1  set hasValue1 = 1 where id = 3
```

I hope you get the idea. The advantages of this structure over your current design would be:

- It requires less disk space because now you have 3 bit fields and 1 number field, as compared to 3 number fields before.
- You don't have to have the foreign key or the indices between two table, which saves marginally on the disk space as well.
- Best of all, the query you need is quite efficient:

  ```
  select * from table1 where hasValue1 is null and hasValue2 is null
  ```

Maybe you should give this a try and see if you find any performance benefits.

**Note**: I work with MS SQL Server, so please excuse me if there are any syntax errors, or let me know if something's unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I can't go with this solution, because the project is only a representation of my actual problem, where there are way more values 'x' could have than 0, 1 and 2. For example if I wanted to add 3 and 4 as possible values, I'd have to add two more columns. Now imagine I want to go up to 100. So this, unfortunately is not a potential solution.

Comment: Fair criticism. And, I didn't realize you might want to go up to 100. But I'd say having 100 bit fields in a table is okay! Unless you might be planning to go above that. I'll admit, I used to hate tables with too many columns, but I have learned that they are sometimes useful. So if you don't like this idea, @GordonLinoff's solution should be better IMO. Having an index would give you a bit of boost in performance that you need. Another thing to try might be to replace `t2.x = 1 or t2.x = 2` with `t2.x in (1,2)` at the end of your subquery.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is I don't know which fields might come up. For example I could need 352, but don't need 175, if you understand what I mean, and the decision which values x can take is not within my power. Sorry I'm talking so cryptic but I don't want to go into domain knowledge. I added an index (even made the combination of the fields a PK), and switched to in (1,2), but didn't get much of performance improvement.

Comment: Maybe you could find out how many different values you would need - through someone who has domain knowledge. If that range is small, I am sure my suggestion would work better. Though, if you had a very large number you run the risk of hitting the limit of maximum number of columns allowed in a table.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using a outer join could be faster:

```
select table1.*
from table1 left join (select table1_id
                       from table2
                       where x = 1 or x = 2) t2 on (table1.id = t2.table1_id)
where t2.table1_id is null;
```